# distance between intersection of two planes and origin

Tags: lagrange-multiplier, plane-geometry

I have a following problem. I want to find the smallest possible distance between the line intersection of two planes given by:

\begin{equation}
x + 2y−2z = 3 \text{ and }  2x + y + 2z = 6
\end{equation}

I already found line of intersection which is given by:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
x &= 3 + 2t \\
y &= − 2t \\
z &= − t
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

But I could not figure out how to use this to find the minimum point so I thought of using Lagrangian method which would look like following:

\begin{equation}
dist = \sqrt{(x-0)^2 + (y-0)^2 + (z-0)^ 2}
\end{equation}

subject to constraints given by the equations of the two planes but the problems seems too unwieldy and difficult. if anyone can help I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Hint: use the square of the distance instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the equations more tractable by using the square of the distance as the objective function instead. However, there’s also a fairly straightforward solution method based on geometric considerations.

The minimal distance to the line is measured along a direction perpendicular to the line, so the nearest point on the line to the origin is the intersection of the line with its perpendicular plane through the origin. You have $(2,-2,-1)^T$ as a direction vector for the line, so an equation of this plane is $2x-2y-z=0$. You will end up with a simple linear equation in $t$ to solve.

Comment: so I could solve it by minimizing \begin{equation}
x^2 + y^2 + z^2  \text{ s.t. } 2x-2y-z=0
\end{equation}?

Comment: @1muflon1 That’s right. $a^2$ is monotone increasing for $a\ge0$, so minimizing that also minimizes nonnegative $a$.

Answer (score 1):

Let us see what happen with the Lagrange Multipliers formulation

$$
\Pi_1\to (p-p_1)\cdot \vec n_1 = 0\\
\Pi_2\to (p-p_2)\cdot \vec n_2 = 0
$$

with $p = (x,y,z)$ are the two restriction planes so

$$
L(p,\lambda_1,\lambda_2) = \frac 12p\cdot p+\lambda_1(p-p_1)\cdot \vec n_1+\lambda_2(p-p_2)\cdot \vec n_2
$$

and the stationary conditions are

$$
L_p = p +\lambda_1\vec n_1+\lambda_2\vec n_2 = 0\\
L_{\lambda_1} = (p-p_1)\cdot \vec n_1 = 0\\
L_{\lambda_2} = (p-p_2)\cdot \vec n_2 = 0\\
$$

then substituting we have two equations and two unknowns $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$

$$
\lambda_1\vec n_1\cdot\vec n_1+\lambda_2\vec n_2\cdot\vec n_1 = p_1\cdot \vec n_1\\
\lambda_1\vec n_1\cdot\vec n_2+\lambda_2\vec n_2\cdot\vec n_2 = p_2\cdot\vec n_2
$$

finally we have after the solutions $\bar\lambda_1,\bar\lambda_2$

$$
p^* = \bar\lambda_1\vec n_1+\bar\lambda_2\vec n_2
$$

so $d = \lVert p^*\rVert$

NOTE

Here the minimization of $\lVert p\rVert$ is equivalent to the minimization of $\frac 12\lVert p\rVert^2 = \frac 12p\cdot p$ and also

$$
\vec n_1 = (1,2,-2)\\
p_1 = (3,0,0)\\
\vec n_2 = (2,1,2)\\
p_2 = (0,6,0)
$$

Comment: so here there would be actually two possible solutions?

Comment: @1muflon1 Only one! The solution point $p^*$ is unique!

Comment: oh okay I was confused by $p_1$ and $p_2$ sorry

Comment: I also have one more question the $\Pi_1$ and $\Pi_2$ conditions mean that the two restriction planes are orthogonal to the line of intersection at the same time?

Comment: @1muflon1 In the Lagrange formulation does not appear directly the intersection line. In this formulation the solution is obtained by the intersection of three planes. Here $\Pi_3\to p+\lambda_1\vec n_1+\lambda_2\vec n_2 = 0$

Comment: Okay but then what would be the interpretation of that the third plane is some plane that crosses both origin at $[0,0,0]$ and the intersection of the two planes, and then we minimize that distance? I am really sorry if my question is stupid but I am completely new to this. I know how to solve Lagrangian and what interpretation is when I am working in 2D space, and finding a distance between lets say intersection of two lines and origin, but adding another dimension just makes everything very confusing for me.

Comment: @1muflon1 $\Pi_3$ is normal to the intersection line because the intersection line has the direction vector $\vec n_1\times\vec n_2$